# windows SOX MP4/FFMPEG support

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, fadein, fadeout, sox

i'm trying to use SOX to cut certain mp3s, convert them to different formats and add fade in-out to the files.

It works fine with mp3 to mp3 but when i try to convert it from an MP3 to an m4r i get the error: "sox FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `m4r'".

I'm using SOX in windows so how can i install the ffmpeg package on top of the SOX so it knows waht to do with the m4r format?

on the same machine i can use ffmpeg to convert from mp3 to m4r just fine. It sucks that ffmpeg doesn't offer FADE for audio.

Answer (score 2):

You may download and install ffmpeg library for audacity and then copy avcodec-52.dll avformat-52.dll avutil-50.dll swscale-0.dll to sox installation directory. Thus you can use sox as :

```
sox -t ffmpeg youFile.wma yourFile.wav
```

Comment: I get: `FAIL formats: no handler for given file type 'ffmpeg'`